# Use *.pth model in C++

Tags: pytorch, yolo, torchscript

I want to run inference in C++ using a yolo3 model I trained with pytorch. I am unable to make the conversions using tracing and scripting provided by pytorch. I have this error during conversion

```
First diverging operator:
    Node diff:
        - %2 : __torch__.torch.nn.modules.container.ModuleList = prim::GetAttr[name="module_list"](%self.1)
        + %2 : __torch__.torch.nn.modules.container.___torch_mangle_139.ModuleList = prim::GetAttr[name="module_list"](%self.1)
        ?                                           ++++++++++++++++++++
ERROR: Tensor-valued Constant nodes differed in value across invocations. This often indicates that the tracer has encountered untraceable code.
    Node:
        %358 : Tensor = prim::Constant[value=<Tensor>](), scope: __module.module_list.16.yolo_16
```

Comment: How are you tracing your model?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3) and consequently [this](https://gist.github.com/lantiga/c066830bc53105f56292783eb7c6faa7)

Comment: I was following the basic [example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html#converting-to-torch-script-via-tracing) 
Now I converted my model using the link you shared. Thanks.

Comment: But with this conversion, I am still unable to load the model in C++. I have the following error:
`what():  [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:209] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl
frame #0: c10::ThrowEnforceNotMet(char const*, int, char const*, std::string const&, void const*) + 0x47`
Do you know what could be the reason. I don't have much idea about this. Thanks

Comment: When this kind of issues pop up, I usually post either on the discuss.pytorch.org or post an issue in the Pytorch issues. I'd suggest to give the official forum a shot first.